# What is the difference in these two tkinter GUI codes . Why in one calc every frame is coming in a different line but in another on the same line

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

- 

DETAILS:

1. I wanted to make a simple calculator in Tkinter.
2. I have attached two codes , I just wanted to know what is the difference between the two codes as in one the buttons are coming 3 in a row but in other it is coming all in a row.

- 

**CODE 1 (in which everything is coming on a different line)**

```
from tkinter import *

def click(event):
    global scvalue
    text = event.widget.cget("text")
    if text == "=":
        if scvalue.get().isdigit():
            value = int(scvalue.get())
        else:
            try:
                value = eval(screen.get())

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                value = "Error"


        scvalue.set(value)
        screen.update()

    elif text == "C":
        scvalue.set("")
        screen.update()

    else:
        scvalue.set(scvalue.get() + text)
        screen.update()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("644x970")
root.title("Calculator By CodeWithHarry")
# root.wm_iconbitmap("1.ico")

scvalue = StringVar()
scvalue.set("")
screen = Entry(root, textvar=scvalue, font="lucida 40 bold")
screen.pack(fill=X, ipadx=8, pady=10, padx=10)

f = Frame(root, bg="grey")
b = Button(f, text="9", padx=28, pady=18, font="lucida 35 bold")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=18, pady=5)
# b.bind("", click)

b = Button(f, text="8", padx=28, pady=18, font="lucida 35 bold")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=18, pady=5)
# b.bind("", click)

b = Button(f, text="7", padx=28, pady=18, font="lucida 35 bold")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=18, pady=5)
# b.bind("", click)

f.pack()


f = Frame(root, bg="grey")
b = Button(f, text="6", padx=28, pady=18, font="lucida 35 bold")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=18, pady=5)
# b.bind("", click)

b = Button(f, text="5", padx=28, pady=18, font="lucida 35 bold")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=18, pady=5)
# b.bind("", click)

b = Button(f, text="4", padx=28, pady=18, font="lucida 35 bold")
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=18, pady=5)
# b.bind("", click)

f.pack()
```

**Code 2(In which everything is there on the same line)**

```
root = Tk()

root.geometry('400x800')


string = StringVar()
string.set("")

def click(event):
    global screen
    text = event.widget.cget("text")
    print(text)
    


screen = Entry(root,textvariable=string,font = 'Algerian 50 bold')
# screen.place(height=70,width = 'X')

screen.pack(padx = 10,pady = 10 , fill = X,ipady=20)

frame1 = Frame(root,bg = "Black")

b = Button(frame1,text = '9',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '8',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '7',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
frame1.pack()


b = Button(frame1,text = '6',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '5',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '4',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
frame1.pack()


b = Button(frame1,text = '3',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '2',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '1',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
frame1.pack()


b = Button(frame1,text = '0',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '+',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '-',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
frame1.pack()


b = Button(frame1,text = '*',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '/',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '%',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
frame1.pack()


b = Button(frame1,text = '**',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = '=',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
b = Button(frame1,text = 'C',font = 'Dolce 45')
b.pack(side = LEFT , padx = 15 , pady = 15)
b.bind('<Button-1>',click)
frame1.pack()





root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your second code is only creating one Frame, and is appending all the buttons to that frame.  Your first code creates a Frame for each row, as it should.